# Is my beam sized properly?

Tags: joists, load-bearing, beam

I’m trying to determine if my beam is strong enough.  Double 2x10 pine 6.5ft long center beam holding up upstairs floor with 16”oc 2x10 floor joists one side are 12.75ft long and 11ft long joists on other side. Using han Any issues?

Comment: "Pine" is ambiguous for spec'ing species. There's Southern Pine and Spruce-Pine-Fir. Turns out that both work, so no big deal. You need to specify a lumber grade. #2 is typically the lowest grade 2×10 that you can buy at the corporate hardware stores. Please edit the goofy auto corrects. I would, but some of them I don't quite understand.

Comment: Are these joists carrying sleeping rooms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming #2 grade softwood, Table R602.7(2) under [IRC R602.7](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-6-wall-construction#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch06_SecR602.7) prescribes a maximum header span of 6'-6" on top of 2 jack studs at each end if your dead load is 10 psf. Your header size, then, is good for a dead load of 10 psf.

Assuming #2 grade softwood, Table R502.3.1(2) referenced from [IRC R502.3.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-5-floors#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch05_SecR502.3.2) prescribes a maximum joist span of 14'-0" if your dead load is 10 psf. The table granularity allows for different species with different spans, but I just chose the worst #2 grade value. Your joist size, then, is okay if your dead load is 10 psf.

If these joists carry sleeping rooms, then the live load is 30 psf instead of the 40 psf live load that I used above. If the live load is 30 psf, then the above checks verify that your floor is good for 20 psf dead load instead of the 10 psf.

Comment: I believe it’s considered live load as it’s mostly a hallway / closet / part of a family room that may have a couch on it.  One side of beam is sitting on header plate supported by (3) 2x4s directly under it.  The other end is a shared post (with another beam) made up of (3) 2x6s and (2) 2x4’s.   Joists have blocks and hangers. 

I don’t understand most the terminology, but think you’re saying it’s sufficient header for intended purpose?

Comment: Believe it’s considered Southern pine

Comment: @JoeZacha, it's a 40 psf live load area by your description, so the 10 psf dead load is your max. OSB for floor sheathing is 2 psf or 3 psf. The 2×10s on 16" centers are about 3.5 psf. That's about 6 psf total before the floor surface material, so the 10 psf sounds okay as long as you're not doing a concrete topping slab nor tile built on top of an old layer of tile. Stuff like that.

Comment: @JoeZacha, if the species is Southern Pine, then that doesn't change anything. Under the IRC's joist tables, the 14'-0" worst case joist was Southern Pine. The header table doesn't differentiate Southern Pine from other species, but based on its worst-case status from the joist table, I assume that the 6'-6" number was specifically from Southern Pine computations.

Comment: 3/4” plywood and the light concrete on top for subfloor.

Comment: @JoeZacha, is this a 2" topping slab of lightweight concrete (about 17 psf plus the 6 psf for a total of 23 psf)? Or is this some kind of thin self leveling compound (about 2 psf for 1/4" plus the 6 psf for a total of 8 psf)?

Comment: It’s the light concrete like they use in apartments on the upper floors.

Comment: Since it’s the lightweight concrete and the 3/4” plywood will it need to be (3) 2x10’s or (4)?

Comment: @JoeZacha, it's the 2" topping slab of lightweight concrete? There are a million caveats in this instance. Under the IRC, it's not allowed for certain seismic zones, for instance. Unfortunately there's no IRC table for your case of a 20ish psf dead load. Running numbers under the National Design Specification (NDS) for 23psf dead load plus 40psf live load (63psf total) and a 24 ft wide house, I get a maximum span of 7'-2" for three 2x10s. To persuade a building official, you might convince him that the table's 10psf+40psf=50psf for 2 plies implies 25psf per ply, so 3 plies is good for 75psf.

Comment: @JoeZacha, (3) 2x10s is adequate if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  The light concrete is allowed here.  Can you confirm the other side of post beam is adequate?  All details are the same except the beam span is 10ft and the be is (4) 2x10’s.  Or should I increase to (5) 2x10s?

Comment: @JoeZacha, at 63psf, your (5) 2×10s are only good for a 9-4" span. Following my logic from earlier (50psf)(5 plies)/(4 plies) = 62.5psf is perfect for your 63psf load, so any 4 ply header from that table can be converted to 5 ply to be suitable for your load (this all assumes that the slab is 2", which you still haven't confirmed). 6 plies of 2×10 are good for about 10'-3", but I can't rationalize that from IRC tables (it comes from the National Design Specification and would require an engineer to persuade a building official). 5 plies of 2×12 can be rationalized from the IRC.